# Не работает автотестирование в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Коллеги, выручайте.

Заказчику понадобилось Unit-тестирование (причем тесты не сильно сложные) (причем именно unit, а не Feature-тесты --> обычно я Feature-тесты делаю в Postman).

Что я сделал --> настроил добавил три строчки в конец phpunit.xml
[image: Код из phpunit.xml]

и в тестовый класс (Unit/ExampleTest класс) --> даже не стал создавать новый, добавил два метода:

Первый:
[image: Код первого тестового метода]

Второй:

```
public function testGetTotalSumReceipt() {

      $data_publications = [
        [
          "title" => "Капитанская дочка",
          "count" => 43,
          "price" => 349,
        ],
        [
          "title" => "Старуха Изергиль",
          "count" => 64,
          "price" => 259,
        ],
        [
          "title" => "Горе от ума",
          "count" => 76,
          "price" => 149,
        ],
        [
          "title" => "Обломов",
          "count" => 32,
          "price" => 529,
        ],
        [
          "title" => "Война и мир",
          "count" => 26,
          "price" => 129,
        ]
      ];

      $data_deliveries = [
        [
          'name' => 'Курьером',
        ],
        [
          'name' => 'Самовывоз',
        ]
      ];

      DB::table('publications')->insert($data_publications);
      DB::table('deliveries')->insert($data_deliveries);

      $receipt = Receipt::create([
        'code' => 'R-12345678',
        'id_employee' => rand(1,10),
        'id_client' => rand(1,10)
      ]);

      Subscription::create([
        'code' => AppHelper::generate_code('S',Subscription::class),
        'id_publication' => 1, // 349
        'count' => 2,
        'id_receipt' => $receipt->id,
        'start_at' => Carbon::now()->addWeeks(rand(1,3)),
        'end_at' => Carbon::now()->addMonths(rand(1,4)),
      ]);

      Subscription::create([
        'code' => AppHelper::generate_code('S',Subscription::class),
        'id_publication' => 2, // 259
        'count' => 3,
        'id_receipt' => $receipt->id,
        'start_at' => Carbon::now()->addWeeks(rand(1,3)),
        'end_at' => Carbon::now()->addMonths(rand(1,4)),
      ]);

      Subscription::create([
        'code' => AppHelper::generate_code('S',Subscription::class),
        'id_publication' => 3, // 149
        'count' => 4,
        'id_receipt' => $receipt->id,
        'start_at' => Carbon::now()->addWeeks(rand(1,3)),
        'end_at' => Carbon::now()->addMonths(rand(1,4)),
      ]);

      // 349 + 777 + 596 = 1722

      $this->assertEquals(1722,$receipt->calculateFullSum());
    }
```

Во втором методе я проверяю итоговую цену, которая сформировалась из подписок --> это как итоговая цена обычного товарного чека в супермаркете, сложенная из товаров.

При запуске тестов php artisan test высвечивается следующая ошибка:
[image: Ошибка при запуске тестов php artisan test]

Моя схема БД:
[image: Картинка из дизайнера phpmyadmin]

Comment: 1. Было бы не плохо делать скриншоты с номером строки. Вот вижу я ошибку, как понять в той ли строке тестового файла?
2. Хотелось бы увидеть от какого класса унаследован тест.

Comment: тест унаследован от базового класса, а что под скриншотом строки? Я там просто пару методов добавил в дефолтный класс ExampleTest.
Одним словом, что надо еще сделать?

Comment: Скорее всего у тебя в `ExampleTest` на 46 строке нет символа `$` у переменной. По этому выше просил скриншот со строками чтобы убедиться, а так только гадать. Ранее уже был подобный вопрос здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491627/how-to-fix-unexpected-t-object-operator-in-laravel

Comment: Блин, логично, но оказывается я вчера несколько часов перебирал варианты и оказалось, что он почему-то не хочет работать с моделью внутри теста. Я убрал всё, оставил в классе теста один метод с одной строчкой dd(Receipt::all()) --> по идее должен вернуть пустой массив, однако выводит ошибку.
https://imgur.com/a/kFRmrin --> в классе теста больше ничего нету, кроме одного метода, где ровно одна строчка.
https://imgur.com/a/6jlQUhO --> ошибка в терминале

Comment: Здесь нужно почитать на тему фабрик: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#writing-factories.

Comment: @gregman Спасибо, а еще надо было заменить TestCase, который внутри Laravel, а не PHPUnit